# Migrate table variables from SQL Server 2008 R2 to Oracle 11g

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying migrate this code from SQL Server to Oracle but I get many errors; please can anyone help me?

Code in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @tblFacultad TABLE
( IdFacultad INT,
  NomFacultad VARCHAR(200)  
);

INSERT INTO @tblFacultad (IdFacultad, NomFacultad) 
    SELECT IdFacultad, NomFacultad 
    FROM FACULTAD_local

SELECT * FROM @tblFacultad
```

Code in Oracle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE objFacultad AS OBJECT
(
   IdFacultad NUMBER,
   NomFacultad varchar(255)
)

/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tblFacultad is table of objFacultad;

/
SELECT IDFACULTAD,NOMFACULTAD BULK COLLECT INTO tblFacultad FROM FACULTAD;
```

When I run the code in Oracle, I get this error:

> ORA-03001: unimplemented feature
>   03001. 00000 -  "unimplemented feature"
>   *Cause:    This feature is not implemented.
>   *Action:   None.
>   Error en la línea: 11, columna: 54

Comment: [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html) is  a desktop tool for working with Oracle SQL and PL/SQL, similar to [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/what-is-sqldev-093866.html) or Toad. I think what you are asking about here is [Oracle SQL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/sql/overview/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define table variables like this in Oracle SQL. You can define collection types, which can then be used as table column types or (more usually) as types within PL/SQL code. For example:

```
create or replace type objfacultad as object
( idfacultad number
, nomfacultad varchar(255)
)
/

create or replace type tblfacultad is table of objfacultad;
/

declare
    demo_t tblfacultad;
begin
    select objfacultad(idfacultad,nomfacultad) bulk collect into demo_t
    from   ( select 1 as idfacultad, 'F1' as nomfacultad from dual
             union all
             select 2 as idfacultad, 'F2' as nomfacultad from dual ) facultad;

    dbms_output.put_line('Array contains ' || demo_t.count || ' elements:');

    for r in (
        select f.idfacultad, f.nomfacultad
        from   table(demo_t) f
    )
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(r.idfacultad || ' ' || r.nomfacultad);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Output:

```
Array contains 2 elements:
1 F1
2 F2
```

Note that the `create type` statements are [SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/Introduction-to-Oracle-SQL.htm), and the section starting `declare` is a [PL/SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/LNPLS/overview.htm) block. When working with Oracle we have to be aware of this distinction. Whether I used PL/SQL Developer, Toad, a text editor or anything else makes no difference.